# Как взять цвет из другого класса?

Tags: javascript, html, css

К примеру у меня есть блок с классом test как написать что бы он брал цвет из body или другого класса.

Comment: Зачем так извращаться?)) Объявите CSS переменную общую для каких-то классов и будет вам счастье)) Ну или можете объявить отдельный класс типа `.blue` и задать его нужным вам блокам. Кстати если ваш блок дочерний, то ещё вам может помочь (наверное) `color: inherit`

Answer (score 3):

## Варианты с помощью CSS:

- Объявление CSS переменной:

  ```css
  :root {
    --bg-color: red;
  }

  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .one,
  .two {
   background-color: var(--bg-color);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  ```
- Объявление отдельного класса для цвета:

  ```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one red">One</div>
  <div class="two red">Two</div>
  ```
- Назначить цвет как у родителя (да, знаю градиент - это не цвет, просто для наглядности использовал, с `background-color` будет ровно тоже самое):

  ```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .one {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  }

  .two {
    width: 50%;
    height:50%;
    background: inherit;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one">
    One
    
    <div class="two">Two</div>
  </div>
  ```
- Сделать прозрачный фон, чтобы цвет был такой же как и в блоке в котором он находится (да, знаю градиент - это не цвет, просто для наглядности использовал, с `background-color` будет ровно тоже самое):

  ```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .one {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  }

  .two {
    width: 50%;
    height:50%;
    background: transparent;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one">
    One
    
    <div class="two">Two</div>
  </div>
  ```

## Варианты с помощью JS:

- Программно достать цвет элемнета и назначить другому:

  ```js
  const blockOne = document.querySelector('.one');
  const blockTwo = document.querySelector('.two');

  const blockOneBGColor = window.getComputedStyle(blockOne).backgroundColor;

  blockTwo.style.backgroundColor = blockOneBGColor;
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .one {
   background-color: red;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  ```
- Если это inline стиль тогда просто используя `style`

  ```js
  const blockOne = document.querySelector('.one');
  const blockTwo = document.querySelector('.two');

  const blockOneColor = blockOne.style.color

  blockTwo.style.color = blockOneColor;
  ```

  ```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="one" style="color: red;">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Используя `CSS пеерменные`, не зря же говориться что `CSS` язык программирования (рофл ^_~)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  --color: red;
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: black;
}

.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: В CSS вроде принято писать переменные в `:root`(тот же `html`).

Comment: @ΝNL993, все зависит от того, где эти переменные планируются к использованию

Comment: @Grundy правильно подмечено, но судя по коду, автор хотел чтобы переменная была "глобальной".

Comment: @ΝNL993 нет, ты не прав ...